# How to calculate the Laplace transform?

Tags: analysis

we know that ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform )\begin{equation}  \mathcal{L} \{t^{5}f(t)\} = (-1)^5\frac{d^5}{ds^5}
F(s)\end{equation}
My question is
\begin{equation}  \mathcal{L} \{t^{\frac{1}{5}}f(t)\} = ?\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

We use the form:

$$\mathscr{L} \left(t^p, p \gt -1\right) = \dfrac{\Gamma (p+1)}{s^{p+1}}$$

Examples:

- $\mathscr{L} \left( t^{1/13} \right) = \dfrac{\Gamma \left(\dfrac{14}{13}\right)}{s^{14/13}}$
- $\mathscr{L} \left(t^{1/8} \sin t\right) = \dfrac{\Gamma \left(\dfrac{9}{8}\right) \sin \left(\dfrac{9}{8} \tan ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s}\right)\right)}{\left(s^2+1\right)^{9/16}}$
- $\mathscr{L} \left( t^{1/5} e^{-2 t} \cos(11t) \right) = \dfrac{\Gamma \left(\dfrac{6}{5}\right) \cos \left(\dfrac{6}{5} \tan ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{11}{s+2}\right)\right)}{\left(s^2+4 s+125\right)^{3/5}}$

Note that is also worth comparing/knowing the Laplace Transform of two other forms $t^{1/2}$ and $t^{n-1/2}, n = 1, 2, 3 \ldots$.